# Extra spaces between non latin characters in plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use non-latin (Russian) characters in ggplot legend, the legend line becomes much longer. This example code shows the problem.

```
test <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), y = c(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 25, 16), label = c('green / зеленый ', 'зеленый', 'red', 'white', 'yellow', 'pink', 'красный', 'синий' ))


ggplot(data = test, aes(x= x, y=y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = label), size = 20) + theme(legend.position    = "bottom") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

[image]

Does anyone know the way to cure it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above code produces "???????" in place of Kyrillic characters in my R GUI.

Comment: I think this should help Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', 'russian')